# JQuery Ajax call send button works but then the dropdown to reopen the email stops working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, email

> So I have reportviewer view for a map application that shows the
>   report in a PDF.  There's an email button on the view that opens the
>   email form. The user inputs their email, subject, etc.  The Send
>   button fires off an ajax call, and on success I'm removing the open
>   class, which closes the email overlay form.
>
> The problem is that the email button stops working after the send. 
>   Any help would be great. If there's anything more I need to add please let me  know as this is one of my first questions on Stacked.

**Edit**: When I took the button outside of the #formContainer, it added the open class to the report-bottom container, but did not open the email form itself. When the #emailButton is inside of the #formContainer, it completely destroys the email button itself.

Here's the updated code as recommended just incase I might have done this incorrectly:

```
  <div class="report-bottom">
    <div id="formContainer" class="btn-group dropup clickable" style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="left:-20px;min-width:363px;padding:15px;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:15px">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="" id="ajaxform">
                <li data-keepOpenOnClick>
                    <input data-keepOpenOnClick type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="To" />
                </li>
                <li data-keepOpenOnClick>
                    <input data-keepOpenOnClick type="text" id="emailAddressCC" name="emailAddressCC" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="CC" />
                </li>
                <li data-keepOpenOnClick>
                    <input data-keepOpenOnClick type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Subject" />
                </li>
                <li data-keepOpenOnClick>
                    <textarea data-keepOpenOnClick id="message" class="form-control" name="message" value="" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </li>
                <li data-keepOpenOnClick ng-hide="true">
                    <input name="DocumentUrl" value="" ng-model="model.pdfUrlForEmail" />
                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>

                <li data-keepOpenOnClick>
                    <button type="submit" id="btnForSubmit" style="float:right" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
                    <button style="float:left" type="button" id="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
                </li>
            </form>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="emailButton" style="height:30px" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Email
    </button>
    <span><i class="sprite open-icon"></i><a ng-click="getPdf(false)">Open</a></span>
    <!--<span><i class="sprite save-icon"></i><a href="#" ng-click="getPdf(true)">Save</a></span>-->
    <button type="button" ng-click="close()">Close</button>
</div>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reset').click(function (e) {
        $('#btnForSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#emailAddress').val('');
        $('#emailAddressCC').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
        $('#subject').val('');
    });
    $("#emailButton").on('click', function () {
        $("#formContainer").toggle();
    });
    $("#ajaxform").submit(function (e) {

        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = "Home/EmailPdf";
        $('#btnForSubmit').prop('disabled', true);
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: formURL,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                $('#emailAddress').val('');
                $('#emailAddressCC').val('');
                $('#message').val('');
                $('#subject').val('');
                $(".dropup").removeClass('open')
                $('#btnForSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
                alert(data);
                console.log('Your email has been sent.')
                //e.stopPropagation();


            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Your email has not been sent.')
                $('#emailAddress').val('');
                $('#emailAddressCC').val('');
                $('#message').val('');
                $('#subject').val('');
                $('#btnForSubmit').prop('disabled', false);
                alert(data);
            }
        });

        //e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

Comment: Excellent first question ;) Well structured, you've talked about your efforts and you've added the important code. +1

Comment: You don't seem to have a handler on the #emailButton, that would be responsible for opening/closing the form. Does the form start as "open"? and then you submit and it closes?

Comment: @Bosworth99 Yes the email button does toggle the form on and off if I haven't already sent the email. Once the ajax call is fired off and the email form closes, it doesn't reopen unless I click it twice.

Comment: @SlavaN. The app itself is in angular.  I just recently took over the app and it has both Jquery and Angular.

Comment: add the code for your emailButton handler. There's nothing here referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a handler on the email button. You seem to be closing the form when submitted, but there is no handling of the state, via this email button.

Check out this very simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5ukqr68/)

UPDATE [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/k5erLc65/1/)

Place this outside of the ajax block, and tweak to fit your needs.

```
$("#emailButton").on('click', function(){
    $("#formContainer").toggle();
});
```

Hope it helps -

Comment: I added the code in the fiddle.  What's happening now is that when I click the email button, it completely disappears. I'll keep playing with it though.

Comment: look at how I changed the markup. I moved the button outside the container that holds the form. the button click acts on that container. You, obviously, don't want the button to be removed ;)

Comment: Ok so now that I moved the button outside of the form container, it now adds the open class to the report-bottom container but does not toggle the email form.  The click function is also outside of the ajax block.

Comment: I also added an ID to the form container, you'd need to either add that or hook jquery up to a class int he $() selector. Update your code, and I'll take another look -

Comment: Hey this should be working. Check out my second fiddle link, I pulled it directly from your markup. Is there anything else that could be impacting this?

Comment: It's still not opening the email overlay.  Do you think it could be some of the inline classes like dropdown-toggle or the data-toggle="dropdown"? I've searched the dropdown-toggle for the project, and this pattern is being used all over the place.  I'm going to take a look at how it works on other views, and hopefully this will give me an idea of to properly use it in this view.  Oh the joys of inheriting code from developers no longer on the team.. I'll keep you posted :)

Comment: Yeah - there might be some auto-magical operations happening here. If you find that classname all over the place, there is likely a handler at a higher level which you might just need to consume.